# React set state property dynamically

Tags: reactjs, state, javascript-objects

I'm using react and I have some methods to set the state of my COmponent separately.
I have the following methods:

```
setLineColor(value){
  this.setState({stroke:value},()=>{
  this.props.data(this.getStyleData());
 });
}
setFillColor(value){
 this.setState({ fill:value},()=>{
 this.props.data(this.getStyleData());
 });
}
setMode(value){
 this.setState({ mode:value},()=>{
 this.props.data(this.getStyleData());
 });
}
```

How can I combine the methods, so that I can have something like:

```
setAttribute(propery,value){...}
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React set state property and its value dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862136/react-set-state-property-and-its-value-dynamically)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this

```
setAttribute(property, value) { 
  this.setState({ [property]: value }, () => {
    this.props.data(this.getStyleData());
  });
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/44267/)