# How to set state property to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am checking to see if the user is on a device smaller than 768px, and if they are I want to set isTop to false. I am running into a few issues. Everything looks to be okay, but I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: _this2.state.isTop is not a function

What I am working with:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.updateWindowDimensions();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
    document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        const isTop = window.scrollY < window.innerHeight - 50;
        if (isTop !== this.state.isTop) {
          this.setState({ isTop })
        }
    });

    this.checkWidth = () => {
        const match = window.matchMedia(`(max-width: 768px)`);
        if (match) {
            this.state.isTop(false);
        }
    };

    this.checkWidth();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.checkWidth);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You are not setting `isTop` state as `false` there. You are invoking `isTop` function(?) with `false`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React set state property dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591430/react-set-state-property-dynamically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax seems to be incorrect for setting the `isTop` state to false. (Source: [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly))

Try this instead

```
this.setState({isTop: false});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare state in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isTop: false}
}
```

To set state

```
this.setState({
    isTop: "YourValue"
});
```

To Fetch

```
this.state.isTop;
```

Not like you did

```
this.state.isTop(false);
```

Comment: There is no need to set constructor